# Почему нету в C console.h у Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Почему нету в C console.h у Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: А он должен быть?

Comment: На макинтоши нету команднои строки потому console.h добавляет консольное приложения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что такого файла нет ни в стандарте C++, ни в стандарте C. Видимо этот файл принадлежит какой-то библиотеке, чтобы его использовать Вы должны установить эту библиотеку самостоятельно.

Comment: Я читаю Стивена Прата говорит что должна быть

Comment: @MaksimSuprunenko, тогда предлагаю задать вопрос Прату, откуда он взял такой заголовок. В Windows SDK есть `consoleapi.h`, но `console.h` — нет.